# Is there a way to digitally sign PDF documents using a USB token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, certificate, adobe

I have been using Python3, [endesive](https://pypi.org/project/endesive/) and a .p12 file to digitally sign PDF documents. The issue now is that I have to use a provided USB token to sign the PDF document but I am not sure how I can interface with the USB application (EnterSafe PKI ePass2003).

I have only been able to export a .cer file from the application, and the USB cannot be directly accessed without the application. However, I can see the certificate from Adobe Reader and I can use Adobe to sign the PDF.

Is there a way to interface with the USB application using Python so I can sign the documents using Python?

Edit: I just found out that the USB application also creates an entry in the windows user certificate store. Not sure if this information will help.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?